# Getting the list of youtube channels for the authenticated user

Tags: c#, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube.net-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to display YouTube analytics data in a .Net application (Asp.net MVC 4 to be specific) using the [google api .net client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/)

The only sample I could find for this was a JavaScript sample located [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/sample-application) for the most parts I was able to recreate the code in .Net, **The only problem is that I don't seem to be able to find the counterpart for this lines of code which returns a list of Channels for the authenticated user**:

```
 var request = gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
      // "mine: true" indicates that you want to retrieve the authenticated user's channel.
      mine: true,
      part: 'id,contentDetails'
    });
```

which should be then used here in my code:

```
 var request = youtubeAnalyiticsService.Reports.Query(
                    "channel=="+ channelId, fromDate, toDate, 
                    "views,likes,dislikes" // metrics to include in report 
                    );
```

What I currently do to get it to work is to copy and paste the channel Id here and therefore "hard-code" it which is not practical in this my case and used only for testing purposes.

Hopefully I'm wrong but after searching for hours I think that the .Net API might be missing this part, can anyone confirm this? and if true are there any alternatives for doing this in the .net application?

I also guess that there might be a straightforward way to just use that part of the JavaScript code in the .net application but I'm not sure how!

Any help, hint or clarification would be much appreciated :)

Comment: does this work when you use the hardcoded Channel Id? if so then replace that channel id with a Parameter..

Comment: @DJKRAZE Yes, it does work that way so I changed the code as you suggested, thanks

Comment: glad that I could provide you with a simple fix

Comment: @DJKRAZE sorry if I caused any confusion, but the problem still exists my answer was to your question asking whether It works if I hard-code the ChannelId or not, the problem is that I'm not able to find a way to get the user's channel Id for the current user.

Comment: yes your question was misleading I will delete my answer..

Comment: look at this link for some references https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_channel_search | this might help as well http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207284/Displaying-Videos-from-YouTube-Channel-in-ASP-NET

Comment: I've already read most of the provided documentations on googlcode in this regard and the only thing I'm missing is the line I mentioned in my question, Thanks anyway though I really appreciate all the efforts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, assuming you've already got OAuth 2 setup and `youtube` is a `YouTubeService` object that's been properly authorized:

```
ChannelsResource.ListRequest channelsListRequest = youtube.Channels.List("id");
channelsListRequest.Mine = true;
ChannelListResponse channelsListResponse = channelsListRequest.Fetch();
string channelId = channelsListResponse.Items[0].Id;
```